# Is there an option to change the space/distance between tick labels and axes labels for plots?

Tags: plotting, labeling

In an attempt to squeeze more plots and controls into the limited space for a demo UI, I am trying to remove any extra white spaces I see.

I am not sure what options to use to reduce the amount of space between the ticks labels and the actual text that represent the labels on the axes.

Here is a small `Plot` example using `Frame->True` (I put an outside `Frame` as well, just for illustration, it is not part of the problem here)

```
Framed[

 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {{Sin[x], None}, {x, 
     Row[{"This is a plot of ", Sin[x]}]}},
  ImagePadding -> {{55, 10}, {35, 20}},
  ImageMargins -> 0,
  FrameTicksStyle -> 10,
  RotateLabel -> False
  ],

 FrameMargins -> 0
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there an option or method to control this distance?

Notice that `ImagePadding` affects distance below the frame label, and not between the frame label and the ticks.  Hence changing `ImagePadding` will not help here.

Depending on the plot and other things, this space can be more than it should be. The above is just a small example I made up. Here is a small part of a UI, and I think the space between the `t(sec)` and the ticks is too large. I'd like to reduce it by few pixels. I also might like to push the top label down closer to the plot by few pixels also.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am Using V9 on windows.

**update 12/22/12**

Using Labeld solution by @kguler below is a good solution, one just need to be little careful with the type-sitting for the labels. `Plot` automatically typeset things as `Text` in `TraditionalFormat`, which is a nice feature. To do the same when using `Labeled` one must do this manually using `TraditionalForm` and `Text` as well.

Here is example to show the difference

**1)**  Labeled used just with `TraditionalForm`. The left one uses `Plot` and the right one uses `Labeled` with  `TraditionalForm`. Notice the difference in how labels look.

```
Grid[{
  {

   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {{Sin[x], None}, {x, E Tan[x] Sin[x]}}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, FrameTicksStyle -> 10, FrameStyle -> 16,RotateLabel -> False],

   Labeled[
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300], 
    TraditionalForm /@ {Sin[x], x, E Tan[x] Sin[x]}, {Left, Bottom, Top}, 
    Spacings -> {0, 0, 0}, LabelStyle -> "Panel"]
   }

   }, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**2)** Now we do the same, just need to add `Text` to get the same result as `Plot`.

```
Grid[{
  {
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, FrameTicksStyle -> 10, 
    FrameStyle -> 16, 
    FrameLabel -> {{Sin[x], None}, {x, E Tan[x] Sin[x]}}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, RotateLabel -> False],

   Labeled[
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300], 
    Text /@ TraditionalForm /@ {Sin[x], x, E Tan[x] Sin[x]}, {Left, 
     Bottom, Top}, Spacings -> {0, 0, 0}, LabelStyle -> "Panel"]
   }

   }, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update 12/22/12 (2)**

There is a big problem with controlling the spacing.

`Labeled` spacing only seem to work for horizontal and vertical spacing, taken togother.

i.e. One can't control spacing on each side of the plot separately? Here is an example, where I tried to move the bottom axes label up, this ended with moving the top label down as well. Which is not what I want.

```
Labeled[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300], 
 Text /@ TraditionalForm /@ {Sin[x], x, E Tan[x] Sin[x]}, {Left, 
  Bottom, Top}, Spacings -> {-.2, -0.7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Will see if there is a way to control each side spacing on its own. Trying `Spacing->{-0.2,{-0.7,0}}` does not work, it seems to take the zero in this case and ignored the `-0.7`

This gives the same result as above:

```
Labeled[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300], 
 Text /@ TraditionalForm /@ {Sin[x], x, E Tan[x] Sin[x]}, {Left, 
  Bottom, Top}, Spacings -> {-.2, -0.7, .0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. there might be a way to specify the spacing for each side with some tricky syntax. I have not figured it out yet. Still trying thing....
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Spacings.html

**update 12/22/12 (3)**
Using combination of `ImagePadding` and `Spacing` should have worked, but for some reason, the top label now is cut off. Please see screen shot. Using V9 on windows

[image]

Note: The above seems to be related to the issue reported here:
[some Graphics output do not fully render on the screen until an extra click is made into the notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16248/some-graphics-output-do-not-fully-render-on-the-screen-until-an-extra-click-is-m)

Need an extra click inside the notebook. Then label become un-chopped !

Comment: Might I suggest you migrate the second half of this post into an answer? I feel this is a fairly frequently asked question, but this post is fairly hard to parse and separate into a question and an answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs The methods shown in [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83636/280) can be used for this, but they seems to be even more convoluted than [Emilio's approach](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81367/280).

Comment: You can simply add spaces before or after the text you want on the lable. E.g. if the lable is "y", you can make it "y " instead. For the other axis, instead of using "x" you can use "\n x" or "\n \n x" for adding one or two spaces before the label.
Cheers!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The most convenient way I found is to  wrap `Plot` (without `FrameLabels` and `PlotLabel` and with appropriate `ImagePadding` and `ImageMargins`) inside `Labeled` and use the `Spacings` option to position the labels:

```
 Labeled[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 ImagePadding -> {{20, 1}, {15, 2}}, ImageMargins -> 0, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> 10], 
 TraditionalForm /@ {Sin[x], x, Row[{"This is a plot of ", Sin[x]}]}, 
 {Left, Bottom, Top}, 
 Spacings -> {0, 0}, LabelStyle -> "Panel"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

This can also be achieved by

- encasing the graphic inside a `Show`,
- setting the outer `Show`'s `PlotRangeClipping` to `False`, and
- adding the labels as `Text` commands inside an [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html).

Thus, for your example, you would do

```
Framed[
 Show[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}
   , Frame -> True
   , FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, 
      Row[{"This is a plot of ", Sin[x]}]}}
   , ImagePadding -> {{55, 10}, {35, 20}}
   , ImageMargins -> 0
   , FrameTicksStyle -> 10
   , RotateLabel -> False
   ]
  , PlotRangeClipping -> False
  , Epilog -> {
    Text[x, {0, -1.4}],
    Text[Sin[x], {-4.12, 0}]
    }
  ]
 , FrameMargins -> 0
 ]
```

which produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can then freely place the label text anywhere within the image box by adjusting the `Text` coordinates.

This has the advantage that (as far as I can tell, on v10.1.0) the resulting styling is identical to that produced by setting the labels via `AxesLabel` or `FrameLabel`; if you want to style them directly then you can do that as well.

Further, this produces an actual `Graphics` object, as opposed to an object with a `Labeled` head, which can be advantageous for manipulating and exporting the resulting plot.

Due credit to David Park's answer on [this comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/kKII7037rso) for pointing out the technique.

Comment: +1. The key point of this technique is that `Epilog` (as well as `Prolog`) never triggers the actual plot range of `Graphics` (even when `PlotRange->All` or `PlotRange->Full` is specified). This feature allows to add graphics primitives outside of the plot range safely. The drawback is that you must adjust `ImagePadding` by hands because `Epilog` also does not affect image paddings even when `ImagePadding -> All` is specified.

Comment: This method is better (IMO) for many reasons; the fact that it produces a `Graphics` object as you say, this also means it can be made a known `ImageSize`, also it gets the alignment of the axes labels correct, the x is beneath the 0. You can make your code more general still by using `Scaled` values for the positions in the `Epilog`, ie replace `Text[x, {0, -1.4}]` with `Text[x, Scaled[{0.5, -0.2}]]` as you then don't need to know the `PlotRange`.

Comment: Is there a reason you have chosen to put the `Epilog` in a `Show` instead of simply within the `Plot`?

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Yes. This lets you set PlotRangeClipping to True for the plot itself. Otherwise it is not necessary.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty, it seems to me that the value of PlotRangeClipping given in the Show overrides that given in the Plot (unfortunately). I guess it might be system dependent (I'm on 10.3 on OS X). If you take your example and set PlotRangePadding->None (so we can observe whether clipping is occurring or not) you will see that adding a PlotRangeClipping->True inside the Plot doesn't stop the plot from slightly spilling over the frame at (-pi,0). I'm wondering how to fix this....

Comment: @Quantum_Oli I can't detect the spilling you mention but you're right that the clipping option for the `Show` can indeed override the one for the inner plot. The problem you mention is, I think, more to do with the corners `Line` object overstepping the bounds, and it's really tricky to control - I usually end up putting white rectangles around the plot whenever this becomes a problem.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty, I believe you are correct, I think my problem was indeed spilling due to the Line thickness, exacerbated due to the fact I am using a small ImageSize as discussed here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29797/plotrangeclipping-not-working-correctly-with-small-imagesize-and-pdf-export

As you mention I have adopted the solution of white rectangles, adding my own PlotRangeClipping option which clips using automatically  positioned rectangles, with the added flexibility of being able to request clipping on each side individually. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Quantum_Oli If you have an automated clipping-by-rectangles solution then I'd encourage you to post it as a Q&A here - it would certainly be something very handy to have around without loads of ad-hoc coding.

Comment: Note that it is handy to use `Scaled` coordinates for label positioning: `Epilog -> {Text[x, Scaled@{1/2, -.1}], Text[Sin[x], Scaled@{-.12, 1/2}]}`.

Answer (score 12):

Another possible (partial) solution is adding negative space.  This can be accomplished by putting the label in [`Framed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html) and setting negative frame margins on one or mode side.

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 Framed[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{Sin[x], None}, 
     (* HERE'S THE FRAMED LABEL: *)
     {Framed[x, FrameStyle -> None, 
       FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, -space}}, 
       ContentPadding -> False], 
      Row[{"This is a plot of ", Sin[x]}]}}, 
   ImagePadding -> {{55, 10}, {35, 20}}, ImageMargins -> 0, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> 10, RotateLabel -> False], FrameMargins -> 0],
 {space, 0, 20}
 ]
```

Adding too much negative space will cause part of the label to be cut off.

Here's a convenience function to shift labels up (positive value) or down (negative value):

```
shift[space_][x_] := 
 Framed[x, FrameStyle -> None, 
  FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, If[space > 0, {0, -space}, {space, 0}]}, 
  ContentPadding -> False]
```

Use it as `shift[amount][label]` and beware of part of the label getting cut off when the shift is not tiny!

Comment: Another issue I found with this approach is that exporting to pdf does not take into account the shifted position and places the frame label at the unshifted location.

Answer (score 11):

When using [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/), we have full control over all label positions.  The key option names are variation on `TextNudge`. The value specified in this option will be added to the label position.

Example with frame labels:

```
Figure[
 {
   FigurePanel[{}, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
     XFrameTextNudge -> 10,     (* shift up by 10 pt *)
     YFrameTextNudge -> {10, 0} (* shift right by 10 pt *)
   ]
 }
]
```

[image]

SciDraw of course draws its own frames and requires working in (and learning) its own framework.  It will not help in changing the position of *standard* frame labels.

The ability of SciDraw to move labels is one of the several reasons why I usually use it for publication figures.  I you have the time and are willing to learn it, it is a good option to deal with the label positioning problem.