# Reduce the space between axis and axes labels

Tags: plotting

```
 x = Table[i, {i, 1, 10}];
 y = Table[i, {i, 1, 10, 1}]
  Datah7 = Transpose@{x, y};
  h7 = ListLogLogPlot[Datah7, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"\[Omega]", 
     "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(\(0\)\(,\)\(c\)\(\\\ \
  \)\)], \(_\)]\) - \!\(\*OverscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(c\)], \(_\
   \)]\)"}, FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Small], PlotStyle -> Blue, 
    PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkersThick"]
```

I simply want to reduce the space between the x-axis and x-axes labels similarly to reduce space between y-axis and y axes labels.

Comment: see if this can help [is-there-an-option-to-change-the-space-distance-between-tick-labels-and-axes-lab](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16802/is-there-an-option-to-change-the-space-distance-between-tick-labels-and-axes-lab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to put the labels as [`Text`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) in an [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
x = Range[10];
y = Range[10];
Datah7 = Transpose@{x, y};
h7 = ListLogLogPlot[Datah7, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Small], PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkersThick",
  Epilog -> {Text["\[Omega]", Scaled[{0.5, -0.05}]], 
    Text[Rotate[
      "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(\(0\)\(,\)\(c\)\(\\\ \
  \)\)], \(_\)]\) - \!\(\*OverscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(c\)], \
\(_   \)]\)", 90 Degree], Scaled[{-0.05, 0.5}]]},
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  ImagePadding -> {{23, 5}, {15, 5}},
  ImageMargins -> 0]
```

[image]