# Change the distance between tick labels and axes labels in small plots

Tags: plotting, labeling, ticks, inset

I produce a plot using

```
ListPlot[{scaled3, scaled2, scaled1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t/t_c", "<X>/t_c"}, ImageSize -> 150]
```

which is intentionally small, because it is meant to enter the inset of a bigger plot. The result is the following:

[image: Plot]

and it is quite clear that axes labels (like "t/t_c" in the picture) are way too far from the tick numbers. How can I reduce this space? Bear in mind that the ultimate goal is to produce a decent looking inset for another plot (simply reducing the fontsize would make the labels barely visible).

I am aware that a very similar question was already asked in an old [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16802/is-there-an-option-to-change-the-space-distance-between-tick-labels-and-axes-lab), but the presentation was very confused; moreover, all the answers relied on the use of `Framed[]`, which rotates the y-axis label by 90°, thus wasting even more space.

Comment: I can propose a workaround. You could make the inset without FrameLabels and then draw the labels separately using the following construct: `Show[{ListPlot[{scaled3, scaled2, scaled1},...], Graphics[{Text[Style["t/t_c",10],{point}],....}]}]` where you select the point "point" such that the label goes into a desired place. For the label at the y axis you will have to also rotate the label.

Comment: When posting questions, please provide code and data for minimal concrete examples that demonstrate the issue. In general, there may be multiple possible approaches depending on the particular circumstances.

Comment: You're certainly right, but in this case you could plot literally any array (instead of ```{scaled3, scaled2, scaled1}```) using the sintax in my example and you would still observe the same problem.

Comment: tried `Labeled[ListPlot[{scaled3, scaled2, scaled1}, Frame -> True,  ImageSize -> 150], {"<X>/t_c",  "t/t_c"}, {Left, Bottom}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, RotateLabel -> True]`?

Comment: @kglr this seems to work pretty well. The only flaw is that the lower label is now placed horizontally at the center of the whole graph (including ticks on the y-axis), which does not coincide with the center of the x-axis (excluding y-axis ticks). Is there a way to slightly pan the label horizontally?

Comment: @DavideVenturelli, please see if the answer I posted gives what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Legended[ListPlot[{scaled3, scaled2, scaled1}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 150], 
 Thread[Placed[{"<X>/t_c", "t/t_c"}, 
        {{Left, {0.1, .4}}, {Bottom, {.4, .7}}}, 
        {Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &, Identity}]]]
```

[image]

Play with the offset positions (`{.1, .4}` and `{.4,.7}`) to put the labels in desired positions.

Using `Labeled`:

```
Labeled[ListPlot[{scaled3, scaled2, scaled1}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 150],
  {"  " <> "<X>/t_c", "  " <> "t/t_c"}, 
  {Left, Bottom}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this completely solves the problem.