# How can we control the space between two successive legends and between label and legend?

Tags: plotting, legending

```
Block[{const = {2.2, 3.1, 3.5}}, 
 plt0 = ListLinePlot[
   Table[{x, Sin[x #]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.05}] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}, FrameLabel -> {"X ", "Y"}, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 50, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{ToString[#] & /@ const}, 
      LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
      LegendMarkerSize -> 8], {{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, -3}}]]]
```

[image]

Is it possible to control the space indicated by the red arrows and make it smaller?

Comment: It would be good to provide a minimal example. This is a question about `LineLegend` I think, so why not make a very simple plot with only the option that causes problems? Also, you use `MaTeX` which is not available by default in Mathematica.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I updated the question

Comment: add the option `Spacings -> {.5,.3}` (replace `{.5, 3}` with your choice) in `LineLegend`?

Comment: @kglr that is exactly what looking for..Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131384/85954) you could try to replace

```
ToString[#] &
```

by something like

```
Framed[ToString[#],
       FrameStyle->None,
       FrameMargins->{{-5,-5},{0,0}},
       ContentPadding->False] &
```

Answer (score 1):

The distance between the line and the figure one can control by placing the empty space after the quote: `"2.2"`, `" 2.2"` or `"  2.2"`. The space between two different legends one can also enter as white space, or alternatively by using `Spacer`. As an example, I give below two images with different spacings:

```
Column[{
  Block[{const = {2.2, 3.1, 3.5}}, 
   plt0 = ListLinePlot[
     Table[{x, Sin[x #]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.05}] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}, FrameLabel -> {"X ", "Y"}, 
     PlotRangeClipping -> False, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 50, 
     PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[LineLegend[{"2.2" Spacer[10], "3.1" Spacer[10], 
         "3.5" Spacer[10]}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
        LegendMarkerSize -> 8], Scaled[{0.5, 1.01}]], 
     ImageSize -> 300]],


  
  Block[{const = {2.2, 3.1, 3.5}}, 
   plt0 = ListLinePlot[
     Table[{x, Sin[x #]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.05}] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-1, 1}}, FrameLabel -> {"X ", "Y"}, 
     PlotRangeClipping -> False, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 50, 
     PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[LineLegend[{"  2.2" Spacer[10], "  3.1" Spacer[10], 
         "  3.5" Spacer[10]}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
        LegendMarkerSize -> 8], Scaled[{0.5, 1.01}]], 
     ImageSize -> 300]]
  }]
```

returning the following:

[image]